# TextView height dependence on font size with wrap_content parameter

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

During layout makeup, I often need pixel-to-pixel equivalence with templates. And with TextView, I have a trouble. It has strange vertical size - it equals to font size with some padding above and beyond - from 1 to 4 dp, I suppose. It is different with different font sizes and styles, and even worse, unpredictably different. Is there any way to disable such padding at all? 
[image: padding in textView]

code example :

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCardData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- android:background="@drawable/red_frame_animation" -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCardNameLabel"
                    style="@style/LabelDefaultText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ncn_name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCardCustomName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    style="@style/PropertyDefaultText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/panel_background"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Upper TextView has font size 16 dp, but occupies about 20-22dp

Comment: You use it in linear layout or what? Give some example

Comment: as a fix I could add fixed height to TextViews, as I done in second TextView in example. But if style changes, that will be hard to change all views correctly.

Answer (score 2):

try `android:includeFontPadding="false"` in your TextViews

Comment: that removes font padding, but I want it's size